# Check if the user is a developer

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I can't purchase in-app content for my app because I'm using the same account on my phone as on Google Developer page.

If the user purchases the "premium" add-on for my app it enables some extra features.

Like this:

---

```
 if(premium == true){
 enable extra features...
 }
```

---

Is there some way check if the user is a developer?

---

```
 if(developer == true){
 enable extra features...
 }
```

---

Comment: Is the premium content based on an in-app purchase or a separate download from Play Store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one.. Get account from device and in case this is tour account allow the features

premission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

Code:

```
Pattern emailPattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS; // API level 8+
Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(context).getAccounts();
for (Account account : accounts) {
    if (emailPattern.matcher(account.name).matches()) {
        String possibleEmail = account.name;
        ...
    }
}
```

Something like that.. Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you, but do you know some way to do this without using any new permissions?

Comment: Yes but it will be to complicated.. There is a thing that is like tracking so you can pass paramter to the download link and the app will know this is your special app
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/campaigns#google-play-how

http://support.mobileapptracking.com/entries/22561636-How-Google-Play-Install-Referrer-Works

Comment: The easiest seems to add some kind of PIN code or password lock that only I know ;)

Comment: The second solution i sent you is great.. You can add parameter to the link in the Google Play and once the app is created you can get the paramter.. This is used for tracking but you can use to identify yourself.. You can try it.. PIN will be not a very good solution because it can affect other users.. Hope that i helped, Thanks